# Ui-router: how to block url navigation but accept state navigation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to do some functionality that accepts a state navigation (using $state.go(otherState)), refreshing the associated url in the adress/url bar but it blocks (or redirects to not allowed page) if user directly puts this url in the adress/url bar.

Could it be done by ui-router rules or something inside ui-router module?

I put the example code:

```
$stateProvider.state("main", {
  url: "/index.html",
  templateUrl: "main.html"
}).state("notAccessibleScreenByBar", {
  url: "/private/example.html",
  templateUrl: "example.html"
});
```

From main view (index.html), the next angular code will be executed:

```
$state.go("notAccessibleScreenByBar");
```

This action changes the view, loading example.html and refreshing the url bar to /private/example.html.

If user puts /private/example.html in the adress/url bar, ui-router must block this request (or redirect to not-allowed page).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do seems very similar to any web authentication standard, but, if you don't want that, you could use `$locationChangeSuccess` ([docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location))

A basic example inspired by [this sample](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider):

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e, newUrl, oldUrl) {

    // Prevent $urlRouter's default handler from firing
    e.preventDefault();

    if(isThisTransitionValid(newUrl, oldUrl)) {
      // Ok, let's go
      $urlRouter.sync();
    });
  });
```